# $.fancybox( elem ) works but $( elem ).fancybox() does not

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

```
Jquery 1.11.1
FancyBox 2.1.5
```

Exactly as the title described,

```
$.fancybox( elem )   // works!
$( elem ).fancybox() // Returns `elem`, but doesn't instantiate the Popup
```

I would just bow my head and go with the first option since it works, but I can't pass options in this way to FancyBox.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: can you provide the link of library|?

Comment: http://fancybox.net/api

Comment: its functions are using jquery namespace format so that's why, see this:http://www.sitepoint.com/5-ways-declare-functions-jquery/

Comment: I'm getting the remote feeling that one of my other libraries might be usurping the call somehow and overriding its insantiations.. Just a wild guess..

Comment: `$( elem ).fancybox()` is just binding fancybox to `elem` but still requires a `click` event (on `elem`) to trigger fancybox. On the other hand, `$.fancybox(elem)` triggers fancybox programmatically using `elem` as its content http://jsfiddle.net/gL9dre97/ and it's equivalent to `$.fancybox({ content: elem });` http://jsfiddle.net/gL9dre97/1/ ... if `elem` is a reference (an inline container for instance), it would be similar to `$.fancybox({ href: elem });` http://jsfiddle.net/gL9dre97/2/

Comment: @JFK Ah brilliant. Wow thanks for that. That's the answer I was looking for if you wanted to post it.

Comment: @Trip : added another case scenario for documentation purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Case 1** :

```
$( elem ).fancybox({
    // API options
});
```

... is just binding fancybox to `elem` but still requires a `click` event (on `elem`) to trigger fancybox. See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gL9dre97/3/)**

**Case 2** :

```
$.fancybox(elem,{
    // API options
});
```

...triggers fancybox programmatically using `elem` as its content. **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gL9dre97/)**

**Case 3** :

```
$.fancybox({ 
    content: elem,
    // other API options
});
```

... it's similar to *case 2* to but using a different syntax. It's normally used to pass any arbitrary HTML as content (it mostly requires `type` to be set as `html`). **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gL9dre97/7/)**

**Case 4** :

If `elem` is a reference (an `inline` container for instance), then you could do

```
$.fancybox({ 
    href: elem,
    // other API options
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gL9dre97/2/)**

**Case 5** :

```
$.fancybox([object],{
    // API options
});
```

... where you can pass a collection of javascript *objects* like :

```
var elem = [{
    href: "images/image01.jpg",
    title: "title 01"
}, {
    href: "images/image02.jpg",
    title: "title 02"
}];
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gL9dre97/6/)**

**NOTE**: All the scenarios above apply to either fancybox v1.3.4 or v2.x

Answer (score 1):

Just going to post this as a partial answer. Using the working non-official syntax, I can write :

```
$.fancybox({ content: elem });
```

Then I can pass options as well as the `elem`